# facebook integration in Application

Tags: objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

I am a new Programmer in Iphone... i wants use facebook in my app..and i wants post wall comment in facebok...

my problem i got following error when i run application....there is only one error......

Undefined symbols:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBStreamDialog", referenced from:

objc-class-ref-to-FBStreamDialog in GApplicationViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    static NSString* kApiKey = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    static NSString* kApiSecret = @"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
    _session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];
    [_session resume];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

thanks for giving your valuable time for my code....

Comment: @DarkDust...thanks.. now i formatted my question...can you got the problem..

Comment: you can try this:- add the static NSString* kAppId = @"appid";  and static NSString* kApiSecret = @"ed329a1963124d849081f1256ac6dde7"; before the class implementation

Comment: BTW, I *really* hope for you that the values in your API key and secret aren't your real key and secret. Otherwise you would need to ask Facebook to give you a new secret, as now everybody could do nasty things through your account.

Comment: @DarkDust thanks... these keys not real...

Comment: but are those in the editing history?

Comment: I wants you to work on your communication skills, or at least your formatting.

Comment: @JamesJohnson ..thanks ..i always try my best here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to link the Facebook library. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231494/facebook-symbols-not-found-for-i386-architecture) (ignore that it's about the simulator, the issue is the same).

Comment: @DarkDust... thanks again... you are right... problem is to link the Facebook library...and also your link helps me..